# Django Template -- Set a value of an element based on some value at other location

Tags: django, django-templates

I don't know whether the title is unclear but I will try to explain it here. First some preface -- what I am trying to do is to show a lost of objects having the same attribute and I want to group them on the basis of another attribute.

1. First I get all the distinct values of first attribute.
2. Second I get all the distinct values of second attribute.
3. Lastly I get the list of all the objects
4. Then I iterate over the column values and display all the objects in the list which have the same value for both the attributes

However there maybe some objects which have the first attribute and not the second so I don't want to display the name of that attribute. Maybe this template snippet will make it more clear. It contains only the `inner two loops`

```
{% for attr2 in attr2_list %}
    <li class='category'>  {{ attr1.attr1 }}
        <ul> 
            {% set counter = 0 %}
            {% for object in object_list %}
                {% if object.attr1 == attr1.attr1 and object.attr2 = attr2.attr2 %}
                    {% increment counter %}
                    <li><a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}"> Test {{counter}} </a></li>
                 {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

What I want is that if the for loop is not satisfied for a particular `attr2` then I dont want to display this `<li class='category'>  {{ attr1.attr1 }}`

I hope I have made myself clear. Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 2):

You’re fighting a losing battle trying to do this in your template: the closest thing to a solution for you here is the [`regroup` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup), but that doesn’t nest the way you’re looking for and relies on the items being sorted on the grouped attribute in the first place.

In your view, you probably want something like this:

```
grouped = {}
for obj in object_list:
    grouped.setdefault(obj.attr1, {}).setdefault(obj.attr2, []).append(obj)
```

This should give you a dictionary where the keys are values of `attr1`, and the values are dictionaries mapping from values of `attr2` to lists of items with those attributes.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of logic is more properly place in the view rather than the template. You could filter these objects quite easily in the view, then pass only the objects that meet the criteria as a named value in the context. I would give you some code, but I don't know what data you're working with.